# Android usage of Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, toast

In my main Activity's `onCreate` method, I've started a `Intent` using the following code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, NetworkHandler.class);
startService(intent);
```

I've created another class named NetworkHandler which extends the `IntentService`

```
public class NetworkHandler extends IntentService {
    public NetworkHandler() {
        super("HTTPRequest");
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        String url = "http://vlm1.uta.edu/~zhangzhong/questions.json";
        Toast.makeText(intent.getComponent(), "Debug!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
```

The problem is I'm trying to use the `Toast` in the `NetworkHandler` class. I'd like to pass the main activity object to the first parameter of `makeText` method of `Toast`. How can I do it?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Surely this isn't about `Toast`...why don't you use an `AsyncTask`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass either `getApplicationContext()` or `this` as the first parameter of `makeText()`.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a Context. Luckily, IntentService is a Context, so just use `this`!